# Using $y = (n / 0)(x - t)$ for the equation of a vertical line

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone tell me if this would be a valid equation for a vertical line?

> y = $(n / 0)(x - t)$
>
> for $n$ = all real numbers $\ne 0$
>
> and $t =$ x-intercept

I've tested it to the best of my ability, and it seems to work fine, though I don't know *all* the rules for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Division by zero is undefined.

Comment: Hmm. I can see there is a lot of debate about dividing by $0$, but I feel that @Goos has explained it clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are defining $a / 0$ to be "the set of all real numbers $b$ such that $b \cdot 0 = a$", then you are essentially correct: $y = (x-t)/0$ gives a vertical line with x-coordinate $t$.

Using division by zero to mean this is highly nonstandard, and if you were going to do so you'd have to be really clear on what you mean.  But the idea of a function taking in a number and outputing a set is actually pretty appealing - not to mention very useful for "multivalued functions" in complex analysis.

Comment: $x - t = 0$, so even with your generosity, it doesn't work.

Comment: @amWhy what do you mean?  When $x - t = 0$, $0/0$ is the set of all real numbers.  Hence the vertical line.

Comment: Not any particular vertical line. We need to know the vertical line to have $x - t = 0!$ y = 0/0 tells us nothing about about the assumption $x = t$, hence does not describe the assumption of the fully defined line, $x = t$. Anyway, I've wasted enough time on this question.

Comment: @amWhy I admit I am a little confused on what you are saying.  If $t$ is a fixed real number, the equation $y = (x-t)/0$ (where division by 0 is defined nonstandardly) gives the vertical line with x-coordinate $t$.  What do you mean, "we need to know the vertical line to have $x - t = 0$"?

Comment: $x - t = 0$ requires (assumes) $x = t$, which is the equation for the vertical line which we are trying to write an equation of the vertical line representing the line already defined by $x = t$. Assuming what we are failing to prove. Having only the equation $y = 0/0$ and reporting that to be a vertical line tells us nothing about which vertical line. As I said earlier, I'm done wasting time here. So I'm sorry if I fail to reply anymore.

Comment: @amWhy I am not assuming $x - t = 0$.  We don't have the equation $y = 0/0$ as you say; we have the equation $y = (x - t)/0$.  If $x = t$, this gives $\{y\} = \mathbb{R}$.  If $x \ne t$, this gives $\{y\} = \varnothing$.  I did not assume $x = t$.  This is *exactly like* the way $\ln z$ would be defined in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A vertical line is given by $\;x = t\;$ where $\,t\,$ is the value of the $\,x$-intercept.

Your equation has $$y = \{\text{undefined}\}$$
since division by zero is undefined, and you are also multiplying by zero, since the only value of $x$ happens to be $t$, the x-intercept.

For a vertical line $x = t$, all values of y are valid (the solution for y consists of $(-\infty, + \infty)$. So the line $x = t$ consists of all the ordered pairs, $$\{(t, y)\mid y \in \mathbb R\}$$

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I believe that this might be a way to represent it in a *y =* format...

Comment: No, it cannot be. You'd need to add limit notation. And even so, what is n approaching, and what is $x$ approaching?

Comment: *x* is any value that can be plugged in for *x*, and *n* is a set of all real numbers excluding 0.

Comment: You cannot write an equation like that. Only one value can be plugged into $x$: that would be $t$.

Comment: Well, it is based on the assumption that 0 / 0 is equal to all real numbers, considering *a* / *b* = *c*, *a* = *bc*, 0 = 0*c*, *c* = all real numbers.

Comment: y = all real numbers, tells us nothing about what $x$ is. It does not tell us what $t$ is, So you are not defining any particular vertical line. You are at best defining one coordinate of the points on a line. At any rate, it is your choice if you want to accept an incorrect misleading answer because it tells you what you want to hear. If you are assuming knowledge of $x = t$, that information gets lost by trying to represent the line only by the equation spitting out what y is.

Comment: *t* is already defined, though.

Comment: But $\bf x$ isn't. You assume ${\bf x} = t$ in order to  use x - t = 0. If we know $x = t$, then we're done!! Why complicate matters by saying anything more, since $x = t$ says it all, already. There are no restrictions on y. I'm done here. You want to hear what you want to hear. Seems nothing I say can encourage you to consider what your critics may have to say.

Comment: Alright, just to wrap this up, what I was originally looking for was a non-standard way to represent a vertical line with an equation. Yes, $x = t$ works, but $y = (x - t)/0$ works as well, and that is more of what I was looking for.